# How to measure time taken of multi-threads created in a loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, time

I want to measure how much time it takes to finish running the code with multiple threads in python.

If I put join inside the loop, it will stop the loop (main thread) from keep creating new threads. It will run the sleep() one by one.

If I put join on the thread which I use to create thread_testing, the join won't work somehow. It prints out the time immediately.

```
def sleep(name):
    print("{} going to sleep".format(name))
    time.sleep(5)
    print("{} wakes up after 5 seconds".format(name))


def thread_testing():
    for i in range(3):
        t = threading.Thread(target=sleep, name='thread' + str(i), args=(i,)
        t.start()
        # t.join() #1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    t = threading.Thread(target=thread_testing, name='threadx')
    t.start()
    t.join() #2
    print(time.time() - start)
```

Desired output:

```
1 sleep
2 sleep
3 sleep
1 wake up after 5
2 wake up after 5
3 wake up after 5 
5.xxx secs
```

Comment: Is there a reason you create a thread which again starts 3 threads?

Comment: @H4kor I did that to force join the thread_testing to main thread so the main will wait till it finish, then run the final timer. But since the threads inside the loop does not have join, so it finish immediately, therefore it's useless ... anyway, thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join will wait for your thread. That is why your threads were executed one by one.
What you have to do is:

- Start all threads
- Store them somewhere
- Once everything is started wait for every thread to finish.

Assuming you don't need the first thread started in main:

```py
import time
import threading

def sleep(name):
    print("{} going to sleep".format(name))
    time.sleep(5)
    print("{} wakes up after 5 seconds".format(name))


def thread_testing():
    threads = []
    for i in range(3):
        t = threading.Thread(target=sleep, name='thread' + str(i), args=(i,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    thread_testing()
    print(time.time() - start)
```